# Detection Color from screen of exe file

Tags: vb6

I have a printer control program( EXE file)

When the printer is working properly, the program shows green color. And displays red color when stopped. Now: I want to write a color recognition code in Visual Basic In such a way that the written program be can detect the color change of that Exe program. That is, to understand when the printer is a stop and when it starts

The code I wrote has a problem : when I put the form on the paint. The color codes care different And I can not do this check with multiple codes

my code:

```
Declare Function GetPixel Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hDC As Long, ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long) As Long
Declare Function GetDesktopWindow Lib "user32" () As Long
Declare Function GetWindowDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long




Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
Dim Pixel As Long
Dim Left As Long
Dim Top As Long
Dim hDC As Long

' Get Desktop window
hDC = GetWindowDC(GetDesktopWindow)

' Use size of screen
Left = Me.Left / Screen.TwipsPerPixelX
Top = Me.Top / Screen.TwipsPerPixelY

Pixel = GetPixel(hDC, Left, Top)

Me.Caption = Hex(Pixel)
Me.BackColor = Pixel
End Sub
```

image1

[image: 1]

image2

[image: 2]

Comment: Does your printer control program draw onto desktop? If it has own window, then you should find its window first.

Comment: if I get the window? Will the numbers of color code be correct?

Comment: I don't know :) You need to try it yourself.

Comment: Your image makes it unlcear what the red / green is rendered on.  It is probably *not* the desktop though.  Try using Spy++ to get information about the actual window that the red/green is painted to, and then use that to get the correct window.

Comment: Thanks
The problem was solved

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Pixel data is taken from the title bar of your window. The red in your image is closer to 236 (236,26,37 is the RGB value) and what your form is showing converts to **137**,126,180 (RGB for 897EB4) and **146**,135,187 (RGB for 9287BB). You can see that the color is wrong because the background of your form doesn't match the red from the desktop.

I would try reading the Pixel further away from the form:

```
Left = (Me.Left / Screen.TwipsPerPixelX) - 20
Top = (Me.Top / Screen.TwipsPerPixelY) - 20
```

Nonetheless, even if the color is affected by the dropshadow, you can implement some tolerance for the value you are receiving. For example, you should accept values within +/- 10 of your expected value using a function like this:

```
Function CheckColor(p_iRed, p_iGreen, p_iBlue, p_iTargetRed, p_iTargetGreen, p_iTargetBlue, p_iTolerance) As Boolean
    CheckColor = CheckColorPart(p_iRed, p_iTargetRed, p_iTolerance) And CheckColorPart(p_iGreen, p_iTargetGreen, p_iTolerance) And CheckColorPart(p_iBlue, p_iTargetBlue, p_iTolerance)
End Function

Function CheckColorPart(p_iValue, p_iTarget, p_iTolerance) As Boolean
    CheckColorPart = (p_iValue >= p_iTarget - p_iTolerance And p_iValue <= p_iTarget + p_iTolerance)
End Function
```

This should handle the slight variations in color you are seeing and detect what you are looking for.